# Hide Picker View Hide Left Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, uipicker

I am trying to hide left up and down arrow. Is there any way to hide left arrow in picker view

[image: Screen shot]

**Code:-**

```
let picker = UIPickerView()
picker.tag = tag
picker.delegate = self
picker.dataSource = self
txtField.inputView = picker
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I m Using `IQKeyboardManager` So below line used for hide the down and up arrow

```
IQKeyboardManager.shared.previousNextDisplayMode = .alwaysHide
```